# Geocoder nearbys method returns nil instead of empty array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-geocoder

I am working in ruby on rails. Rails version **3.2.14**. I have been using `gem geocoder` to geocode current_location based on latitude and longitude and it is working awesome. Now I have been trying to use [nearbys](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) method of geocoder it returns nil instead of an empty array.

**Code:**

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])

@near_by_users = @user.nearbys(30)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you just want to do `@nearby_users = @user.nearbys(30) || []`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this link the method you are trying is depricated:

https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#116-2012-dec-24

[image: Geocoder wiki]